# Upload file using Perl CGI

Tags: html, perl, cgi

I am able to create my directory but I cannot seem to place the file in the directory.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Cwd;
use CGI;

my $dir = getcwd();
print "Current Working Directory: $ dir\n";

my $photoDir = "$dir/MyPhotos";

mkdir $photoDir
        or die "Cannot mkdir $photoDir: $!"
        unless -d $photoDir;
        
        
my $query = new CGI;
my $filename = $query->param("Photo");
my $description = $query->param("description");

print "Current filename: $filename\n";

my ( $name, $path, $extension ) = fileparse ( $filename, '\..*' ); $filename = $name . $extension;
print $filename;
my $upload_filehandle = $query->upload("Photo");



open ( UPLOADFILE, ">$photoDir/$filename" )
 or die "$!"; 
binmode UPLOADFILE; 

while ( <$upload_filehandle> ) 
{ print UPLOADFILE; } 
close UPLOADFILE;
```

The CGI stack trace shows no errors but the log shows there is no output

```
LOG: 5 5020-0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%0-9: CGI output 0 bytes.
```

Comment: Can you include Data::Dumper and dump out to the console what $upload_filehandle is, and post that to your question? (You want the original ">" append mode for open, as well.)

Comment: i am afraid i dont understand how to execute that 'Data : Dumper", i am running this as a localhost perl cgi and the only i can see is the log file. Is there a way to print $upload_filehandle

Comment: http://search.cpan.org/~smueller/Data-Dumper-2.131/Dumper.pm - it is included in the newer versions of perl, and it works wonders for debugging, as it can be used to print complex data structures to STOUT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** This answer is [outdated](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI#Older-ways-to-process-file-uploads), today you will get an [IO::File](https://metacpan.org/pod/IO::File) compatible handle directly:

```
# undef may be returned if it's not a valid file handle
if ( my $io_handle = $q->upload('field_name') ) {
    open ( my $out_file,'>>','/usr/local/web/users/feedback' );
    while ( my $bytesread = $io_handle->read($buffer,1024) ) {
        print $out_file $buffer;
    }
}
```

Please see the [updated documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI#Processing-a-file-upload-field).

---

*Original answer:*

CGI.pm manual suggests this path to saving uploaded files. Try this additional check and write method and see if it helps.

```
     $lightweight_fh  = $q->upload('field_name');

     # undef may be returned if it's not a valid file handle
     if (defined $lightweight_fh) {
       # Upgrade the handle to one compatible with IO::Handle:
       my $io_handle = $lightweight_fh->handle;

       open (OUTFILE,'>>','/usr/local/web/users/feedback');
       while ($bytesread = $io_handle->read($buffer,1024)) {
         print OUTFILE $buffer;
       }
     }
```

Also make sure you have your HTML form has required type like this: `<form action=... method=post enctype="multipart/form-data">`

Comment: This is temporary variable to hold data in. You can define it just before the while loop as 'my $buffer;'

Comment: That worked but i did not end up using the buffer, the problem was that i did not have permissions to write to that directory